# Unequal dimension inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $0=a_{0}\lt a_{1}\lt ... \lt a_{n}$ and $a_{i+1}-a_{i}\le 1$ for $0\le i\le n-1$. Then, prove that $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}\right)^2 \ge \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}^3$$I tried setting $b_{i}=a_{i}-a_{i-1}$ but it doesn't help leaving me clueless. Even if i try to use trigonometric substitution, how do i do it? also the LHS and the RHS have different dimensions....should that give a clue or is there a general method to solve such questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mathematical induction here, using that:

- $a_k \geq a_{k+n}-n$
- $a_k \leq k$
- ${\sum_{i=0}^{k}}\space a_k\geq k\cdot a_k-\frac{k\cdot(k-1)}{2}$

Then try proving that:

$$\left({\sum_{i=0}^{k}}\space a_k+a_{k+1}\right) ^2\geq {\sum_{i=0}^{k}}\space {a_k}^3+{a_{k+1}}^3$$

This also can be rewritten as:

$$2\cdot\left({\sum_{i=0}^{k}}\space a_k\right)\cdot a_{k+1}+a_{k+1}^2\geq{a_{k+1}}^3$$